# Add multiple related objects to a parent model with Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to **add** **multiple** related objects to a parent object with Django.
The error i get: `int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Tag'`

My code looks like this:

```
def ask(request):

    form = AskQuestionForm

    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = AskQuestionForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():

            tags = request.POST.getlist('tags')

            # Category
            qcat = Category.objects.filter(id=request.POST.get('category')).first()

            o = Question.objects.create(
                title = request.POST.get('title'),
                body = request.POST.get('body'),
                category = qcat,
                user = request.user
            )

            for t in tags:
                rt = Tag.objects.get_or_create(word=t)
                o.tags.add(rt)

            return redirect('questions.index')

    return render(request, 'questions/ask.html', {
        'form' : form
    })
```

I want to add tags to question object. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

`get_or_create()` returns a **tuple** of `(object, created)`.  So change the tag creation to:

```
rt, _ = Tag.objects.get_or_create(word=t)
```

Comment: what is the underscore?

Comment: It is just a name of the variable.  You can name it `created` if you want: `rt, created = ...`